# How to "extract" values from Multidimensional Array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I'm unable to figure out how to get the values I need from this array ::: the values I need for the 3 vehicles is .

1. **[class] => span3 scrape_img** the image Href & image src
2. **[class] => price scrape_price** the price
3. **[class] => scrape_make** the make
4. **[class] => scrape_year** the year

I've tried to figure this out by going through [PHP array documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array.php) without much success.

```
Array
(
    [query] => Array
        (
            [count] => 12
            [created] => 2013-02-04T17:46:34Z
            [lang] => en-US
            [results] => Array
                (
                    [div] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [class] => span3 scrape_img
                                    [span] => Array
                                        (
                                            [class] => scrape
                                            [a] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [href] => http://cant-reveal-this.com/cars/hyundai/ix35-2-0gls-auto/
                                                    [img] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [alt] => Featured Image
                                                            [src] => /wp-content/uploads/2013/02/01863-270x150.jpg
                                                        )
                                                )
                                        )
                                )

                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [class] => price scrape_price
                                    [p] => From R249,900
                                )

                            [2] => Array
                                (
                                    [class] => span3 scrape_img
                                    [span] => Array
                                        (
                                            [class] => scrape
                                            [a] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [href] => http://cant-reveal-this.com/cars/hyundai/ix35-2-0gls/
                                                    [img] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [alt] => Featured Image
                                                            [src] => /wp-content/uploads/2013/02/1930-270x150.jpg
                                                        )
                                                )
                                        )
                                )

                            [3] => Array
                                (
                                    [class] => price scrape_price
                                    [p] => From R239,900
                                )

                            [4] => Array
                                (
                                    [class] => span3 scrape_img
                                    [span] => Array
                                        (
                                            [class] => scrape
                                            [a] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [href] => http://cant-reveal-this.com/cars/ford/everest-3-0-tdci-xlt-4/
                                                    [img] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [alt] => Featured Image
                                                            [src] => /wp-content/uploads/2013/02/1876-270x150.jpg
                                                        )
                                                )
                                        )
                                )

                            [5] => Array
                                (
                                    [class] => price scrape_price
                                    [p] => From R279,900
                                )
                        )

                    [span] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [class] => scrape_make
                                    [strong] => Make
                                    [content] => hyundai
                                )

                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [class] => scrape_year
                                    [strong] => Year
                                    [content] => 2011
                                )

                            [2] => Array
                                (
                                    [class] => scrape_make
                                    [strong] => Make
                                    [content] => hyundai
                                )

                            [3] => Array
                                (
                                    [class] => scrape_year
                                    [strong] => Year
                                    [content] => 2011
                                )

                            [4] => Array
                                (
                                    [class] => scrape_make
                                    [strong] => Make
                                    [content] => ford
                                )

                            [5] => Array
                                (
                                    [class] => scrape_year
                                    [strong] => Year
                                    [content] => 2011
                                )
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

Comment: Class elements are accessed differently from array elements (using `->` instead of `[]`)

Comment: @Walfie could you please elaborate some more

Comment: Can you try this and tell me if it returns anything? `$array['query']['results']['div'][0]->span[0]->a['href']`

Comment: @Walfie I get this error >>> Fatal error: Cannot use string offset as an array in  ::: Not sure if I'm doing it right this is how I created $array variable **$array = 'Array( [query] => Array ( [count] => 12 .... )'**

Comment: Do you mean the array in your post isn't the result of a `print_r()` of a variable in your code? How are you getting the array listing in the first place?

Comment: I'm getting the array with print_r()

Comment: Don't create an `$array` variable from the string; use whatever variable you passed in to `print_r()` to access the array elements. I just used the name `$array` because I don't know the name of your array variable.

Comment: With  **$array['query']['results']['div'][0]** I get >> array(2) { ["class"]=> string(16) "span3 scrape_img" ["span"]=> array(2) { ["class"]=> string(6) "scrape" ["a"]=> array(2) { ["href"]=> string(79) "http://cant-reveal.com/cars/hyundai/ix35-2-0gls-auto/" ["img"]=> array(2) { ["alt"]=> string(14) "Featured Image" ["src"]=> string(45) "/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/01863-270x150.jpg" } } } }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you were able to figure it out from the comments and the other answer. However, I should clarify that my comments on the question were slightly misleading, so you can disregard them. I actually assumed `class` referred to PHP objects, when in fact `class` was simply a key for a string (the array looks to me like some parsed HTML/XML). I realized this when you posted a `var_dump()` of the array in the comments.

The issue is that the array structure is fairly complicated with all the nesting going on, so it may be difficult to see what's what. In general, I agree with the other answer; debugging with `var_dump()` is a great way to check. Here's my take on what the answer might be.

Assuming your array variable is `$array`:

1.

```
$array['query']['results']['div'][0]['span']['a']['href']
$array['query']['results']['div'][0]['span']['a']['img']['src']
```

2.

```
$array['query']['results']['div'][1]['span']['p']
```

3.

```
$array['query']['results']['span'][0]['content']
```

4.

```
$array['query']['results']['span'][1]['content']
```

Comment: THX, for your feedback, the way you are demonstrating is how I was able to get all my values.

Answer (score 1):

try this:
if this array is in a variable named `$array`

1-`$array['query']['result']['div'][0]['a']['href']`

2-`$array['query']['result']['div'][1]['p']`

3-`$array['query']['result']['span'][0]['class']`

To debug and find the desired value, try to do like that,

```
var_dump($array['query']);
```

then

```
var_dump($array['query']['result']);
```

...etc

Comment: @khane I get the following error >>> Fatal error: Cannot use string offset as an array

Comment: @khane see my comment above when I use **$array['query']['result']['div'][0]** If I add eg. ['a'] I get errors.

Comment: I know, the answer i gave is incorrect, but, try to follow the debug method,personally i usually use this debug method to find out the value.

Comment: Because, you have object and array element in this array, sometimes, you will use "->" for object and ['namekey'] for array.

Comment: THX to you and @whalfie, I was able to figure it out with your advice